# laravel insert data using DB:Transaction not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, transactions, laravel-8

laravel insert data using DB:Transaction not working

before using db transaction it was working
I thought the problem in the validation but I think it almost right
where is the problem .. I'm trying using transaction for the first time

```
public function createDone(MainCategoryRequest $request){
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        // Insert new main category
        $new_mainCategory = Category::create([
            'slug' => $request->slug,
            'is_active' => $request->is_active, // Use $is_active here
        ]);

        if ($new_mainCategory) {
            // Create category translations
            CategoryTranslation::create([
                'category_id' => $new_mainCategory->id,
                'locale' => 'en',
                'name' => $request->name_en,
            ]);

            CategoryTranslation::create([
                'category_id' => $new_mainCategory->id,
                'locale' => 'ar',
                'name' => $request->name_ar,
            ]);
        }
        // Commit the transaction
        DB::commit();
        // Return a success response
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Category created successfully'], 201);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Something went wrong, rollback the transaction
        DB::rollback();
        // Handle the exception (log, return error response, etc.)
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Failed to create category'], 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also check Exception message by `Log::info(print_r($e->getMessage(), true));` to check what is the actual error.

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth `Log::info($e->getMessage());`. is enough, no need to use `print_r()`.

Comment: "*thought the problem in the validation but I think it almost right where is the problem*" - if you're not sure the problem is with validation or transactions, you need to do some debugging.  What is actually happening, do you see some errors, or ...? `dd($request->all);` before your `try/catch` will tell you if it passes validation. Are your models getting created?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a closure for the transactions instead of explicitly calling `beginTransaction()` and `commit()` or `rollback()`.

**WHY CLOSURE ?**

When you use a closure, the Laravel framework automatically handles the beginning and ending of the transaction for you. This ensures that all operations within the closure either succeed together (and are committed) or fail together (and are rolled back), maintaining data integrity. Without using a closure, you would have to manually begin the transaction, perform your database operations, and then either commit, if all operations were successful or rollback if any operation failed. Using a closure simplifies this process and reduces the chances of errors related to transaction management.

Here's how you can refactor your code to use a closure, and throw exceptions:

```
public function createDone(MainCategoryRequest $request) {
    try {
        DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {
            // Insert new main category
            $newMainCategory = Category::create([
                'slug' => $request->slug,
                'is_active' => $request->is_active,
            ]);

            if (!$newMainCategory) {
                throw new \Exception('Failed to create main category');
            }
    
           // Create category translations
            $translations = [
                ['locale' => 'en', 'name' => $request->name_en],
                ['locale' => 'ar', 'name' => $request->name_ar]
            ];

            foreach ($translations as $translation) {
                CategoryTranslation::create([
                    'category_id' => $newMainCategory->id,
                    'locale' => $translation['locale'],
                    'name' => $translation['name'],
                ]);
            }

            
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
    
        \Log::info($e->getMessage()); // logs an error in your log file 
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Failed to create category'],500);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you use a closure, the Laravel framework automatically handles the beginning and ending of the transaction for you. This ensures that all operations within the closure either succeed together (and are committed) or fail together (and are rolled back), maintaining data integrity.  Without using a closure, you would have to manually begin the transaction, perform your database operations, and then either commit, if all operations were successful or rollback if any operation failed. Using a closure simplifies this process and reduces the chances of errors related to transaction management.